# Java Unexpected Incrementing

Tags: java, increment

Output

5

6

7

Why is the first print 5 and not 6?  Shouldn't the return statement increment as its returned?

```
public class Bravo
{
  protected static int varBravo = 5; 

  protected static int add()
  {
    return varBravo++;
  }
}

public class Alpha
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println(Bravo.add());
      System.out.println(Bravo.add());
      System.out.println(Bravo.add());
    }
}
```

The only time I get "expected" behavior is when I have

```
varBravo++;

return varBravo;
```

which prints

6

7

8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `return varBravo++;` does is it does the statement (return) first, then increments the variable. To achieve what you want (increment, then return) do either what you mentioned above:

```
varBravo++;
return varBravo;
```

or:

```
return ++varBravo;
```

This increments the variable, then does the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ah the classic pre-increment post-increment question. `x++` Increments `x`, but the value that is returned is the value of `x` *before* the increment.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're using `return varBravo++` rather than `return ++varBravo`. `varBravo++` remembers the value, increments the variable, then returns the remembered value, while `++varBravo` increments the variable first, then returns its value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm correct. It's possible the ++ operator gets executed after the return. Try `return (varBravo++)`. Not sure if Java has `++varBravo`, that's how you'd do it in C.

Comment: Interesting, would have thought Java has to evaluate the bracket before returning. Anyway, since Java has ++var as I can see from the other answers, that the way to do it